# It is possible to upgrade a Python installation?

Tags: installation, python

I installed Python 3.6 (on Windows, but the question is also relevant to Linux) and would like to **upgrade this installation** to 3.7.

I know I can install another version in parallel and that they will not collide (I have done this since early 2.7 versions) but I am now wondering about a way to install a new version on top.

The main reason is to keep all installed modules, which I usually have to hunt down and reinstall manually. The aesthetical aspect of having just one version is also there (I understand the implications)

Upgrading would be the ideal path (but I have never heard of that). As a fallback, installing a new one with a simple way to port the modules is fine as well.

Comment: You would have to reinstall the nodules regardless to avoid compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible to have multiple different binary versions (on my system, I have `python2` `python2.7` `python3` `python3.6` `python3.7`) all with different modules available to each binary.

Virtual environments are often used to solve the problem that you will come across with this setup -- different versions of Python with different module dependencies.

After working with Python for a while, the variation in different Python binaries with corresponding module version variations can become very difficult to keep track of.

[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) allows you to finely tune different environments on a project by project basis.

You will find that you have to reinstall non-standard library modules within each virtual environment, but it's easier to keep track of things once you have done this.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I know how to have several installations in parallel (and virtual env as well, which I did not mention). My point was about the ability to have (ideally) one environment upgraded version after version, or (a possibility as well), to cleanly import in the parallel install the current modules (non-standard, obviously, as these will come in with the install)

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible. You can run 3.6 and 3.7 side by side but you have to manage the external modules separately for both installations